# How to draw a path near the nodes?

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-arrows, tikz-node

Here is MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,english,hebrew,numbers=noenddot]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm,tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    % Nodes:
    \node (s) at (-2,0) {$\bullet$};
    \node (a1) at (-1, 2) {$\bullet$};
    \node [opacity=0.2] (e) at (2,0) {$\star$};

    % Paths:
    \draw [->] plot coordinates {(s) (e)}; 
    \draw[blue,dotted,->] plot[smooth,tension=0.5, left] coordinates  {(s) (a1) (e)};
    
\end{tikzpicture}
\par\end{center}
\end{document}
```

This is the output:
[image]

As you can see the `→` at the end is on the star *(node (e))*:
[image]

There is way that the path will end near the node and **not** inside it?
I tried things like `outer sep` but it doesn't help :-(

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Have you tried `shorten >=`?

Comment: @Rmano - where I Put it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using

```
\draw[blue,dotted,->, shorten >=3pt] plot[smooth,tension=0.5, left] coordinates  {(s) (a1) (e)};
```

you have:

[image]

Comment: Thank you Rmano! It's really helps!! :)

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, you can specify the `north west` anchor of node `e` as target for the arrow. With `inner sep` of node `e` you can then adjust the distance.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    % Nodes:
    \node (s) at (-2,0) {$\bullet$};
    \node (a1) at (-1, 2) {$\bullet$};
    \node [opacity=0.2,inner sep=0pt] (e) at (2,0) {$\star$};

    % Paths:
    \draw [->] plot coordinates {(s) (e)}; 
    \draw[blue,dotted,->] plot[smooth,tension=0.5, left] coordinates  {(s) (a1) (e.north west)};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]